# Why Here Maps Routes App and Web Different

Tags: maps, here-api

We have here api on both mobile apps(Android and Ios) and web app(client dashboard) - and we have a problem encountered when we add truck parameters in api request - sometimes routes differ on mobile API and web API, we used totally same parameters, bu in the end routes still different, and we cant figure what else to change to make them same.
Here's one test example:

```
point1 = 37.7793808,-122.4184174(San Francisco),
point2 = 40.7559247,-73.9846107(New York),
vehicleWidth = 300 feet,
vehicleHeight = 400 feet,
vehicleLength = 200 feet,
limitedVehicleWeight = 50 lbs,
```

web part request:

```
var routingParameters = {
 'mode': 'fastest;truck;traffic:enabled;boatFerry:-1',
 'representation': 'display',
 'routeAttributes':  'waypoints,summary,shape,legs'
};
var feet = 0.3048;
var ton = 0.00045359237;

routingParameters.vehicleWidth = (300 * feet);
routingParameters.vehicleHeight = (400 * feet) + 'm';
routingParameters.vehicleLength = (200 * feet) + 'm';
routingParameters.limitedVehicleWeight = (50 * ton) + 't';
for (var x = 0; x < points.length; x++) {
 var point = points[x];
 routingParameters['waypoint' + x] = 'geo!' + point.lt + ',' + point.lng;
}
var router = platform.getRoutingService();
var onResult = function (result) {
```

And then we display route.
As a result we have this route
[image]

Same stuff on app side(Ios example):
v

```
ar stops = [NMAWaypoint.init(geoCoordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: Double(trip.startLatitude) ?? 0, longitude: Double(trip.startLongitude) ?? 0), waypointType: .stopWaypoint)]

stops.append(NMAWaypoint.init(geoCoordinates: NMAGeoCoordinates(latitude: Double(trip.endLatitude) ?? 0, longitude: Double(trip.endLongitude) ?? 0), waypointType: .stopWaypoint) )


let routingMode = NMARoutingMode.init(routingType: NMARoutingType.fastest, transportMode: NMATransportMode.truck, routingOptions: NMARoutingOption.avoidBoatFerry)

let dimensions = TruckDimensions.getSingleEntity()
routingMode.vehicleWidth = dimensions.width.floatValue * feet
routingMode.vehicleHeight = dimensions.height.floatValue * feet
routingMode.vehicleLength = dimensions.length.floatValue * feet
routingMode.limitedVehicleWeight = dimensions.weight.floatValue * ton

let penalty = NMADynamicPenalty.init()
penalty.trafficPenaltyMode = NMATrafficPenaltyMode.optimal
coreRouter.dynamicPenalty = penalty

progress = coreRouter.calculateRoute(withStops: stops, routingMode: routingMode) { (result, error) in
```

And as result we're getting totally different route:
[image]

We found all the parameters that sent by default with app request and tried to do same on web part(at least one that we found on documentation, as its quite empty):
[image]

But nothing helped, routed still different. Our guess that web and mobile API uses different calculations on api side, but we cant find any proofs. How can we have both app side and web side api's with trucks parameters give us same routes? This is critical part of the logic.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The base algorithms are or started the same, but the code base has diverged between the mobile SDK and web services in the last years.
The Web services have newer features like HSP (historical speed patterns), but the mobile SDK service does not (and can not). Therefore you might get slightly different results.

The mobile SDK route calculation might also be done in offline mode, where the algorithm is different for sure.